# DateTime field in DAC causes exception

Tags: acumatica

I tried to create a Screen in acumatica/lexbizz, which should display all entries for my newly created DAC in a simple grid view. The graph looks like this:

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Data.BQL.Fluent;
using PX.LotSertialNbrAttribute.Ext;

namespace Maut1
{
    public class TestMaint : PXGraph<TestMaint>
    {
        public SelectFrom<M1InventoryLotSerialContainer>.View InventoryLotSerialContainers;

    }
}
```

and the used DAC M1InventoryLotSerialContainer contains two Date fields declared like this:

```
        #region ValidFrom
        [PXDBDate()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Valid from")]
        public virtual DateTime? ValidFrom { get; set; }
        public abstract class validFrom : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<validFrom> { }
        #endregion

        #region ValidTo
        [PXDBDate()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Valid to")]
        public virtual DateTime? ValidTo { get; set; }
        public abstract class validTo : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<validTo> { }
        #endregion
```

and I created both fields in the SQL table as nullable and of type [datetime]. I can manage to create new entries in the table by using an already existing screen, but when I try to access my newly created GridView I get the following exception and there are no entries displayed:

```
5/12/2021 3:42:27 PM Error:
Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Valid to: Specified cast is not valid..

System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_DateTime()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetDateTime(Int32 i)
   at PX.Data.PXDataRecord.GetDateTime(Int32 i) in C:\Users\svc-builder\AppData\Local\Temp\~PX.Data.0\PX.Data.dll.il:line 769081
   at PX.Data.PXDBDateAttribute.RowSelecting(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e) in C:\Users\svc-builder\AppData\Local\Temp\~PX.Data.0\PX.Data.dll.il:line 856111
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowSelecting(Object item, PXDataRecord record, Int32& position, Boolean isReadOnly) in C:\Users\svc-builder\AppData\Local\Temp\~PX.Data.0\PX.Data.dll.il:line 666901
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowSelecting(Object item, PXDataRecord record, Int32& position, Boolean isReadOnly) in C:\Users\svc-builder\AppData\Local\Temp\~PX.Data.0\PX.Data.dll.il:line 666757
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Select(PXDataRecord record, Int32& position, Boolean isReadOnly, Boolean& wasUpdated) in C:\Users\svc-builder\AppData\Local\Temp\~PX.Data.0\PX.Data.dll.il:line 644916
   at PX.Data.PXView.CreateItem(PXCache cache, PXDataRecord record, Int32& position, Boolean isReadOnly, Boolean& wasUpdated) in C:\Users\svc-builder\AppData\Local\Temp\~PX.Data.0\PX.Data.dll.il:line 685666
   at PX.Data.PXView.CreateResult(PXCache[] caches, PXDataRecord rec, Boolean hascount, Boolean& overrideSort, Boolean& extFilter) in C:\Users\svc-builder\AppData\Local\Temp\~PX.Data.0\PX.Data.dll.il:line 685586
   at PX.Data.PXView.GetResult(Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, Boolean reverseOrder, Int32 topCount, PXSearchColumn[] sorts, Boolean& overrideSort, Boolean& extFilter) in C:\Users\svc-builder\AppData\Local\Temp\~PX.Data.0\PX.Data.dll.il:line 685520
   at PX.Data.PXView.Select(Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows) in C:\Users\svc-builder\AppData\Local\Temp\~PX.Data.0\PX.Data.dll.il:line 690963
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows) in C:\Users\svc-builder\AppData\Local\Temp\~PX.Data.0\PX.Data.dll.il:line 981069
```

As far as I can understand acumatica is not able to cast the field `Valid to` as a [datetime]. I already tried to use the type [datetime2] in my SQL table, but nothing changed. So I'm not quite sure if either the field is declared wrongfully in the DAC or if I have to use a different type in the SQL table.

BTW this is my first question posted on stackoverflow, so Feedback is appreciated on how to improve on questions in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by generating the DAC in the Customization Editor from the SQL table. After that I could apply all changes I needed inside the DAC while checking if the view is still correct every few fields. Quite a tedious process. This way I could narrow the problem down to a different field that was defined like this:

```
        #region CustomerID
        [CustomerActive(DisplayName = "Customer ID", DescriptionField = typeof(Customer.acctName))]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer ", Enabled = false)]
        [PXDBInt]
        public virtual int? CustomerID { get; set; }
        public abstract class customerID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<customerID> { }
        #endregion
```

The Attribute [PXDBInt] is already included when [CustomerActive] is used. By deleting [PXDBInt] from the CustomerID field the duplicate is removed and the DAC can be correctly used on my screen. I'm still not completely sure why acumatica mentioned the field ValidTo in the exception, because for this field there are no changes necessary. For the future I will be more aware of the Exception messages, apparantly they can be a little confusing and lead in a wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your customization page definition, my guess is that you created the wrong kind of control to present your date field.  Go into 'Customization Project Editor', click on your screen under the 'Screens' header, Click on your grid, click on the 'Add Data Fields' column on the right.  Check for your 'Valid To' field and make sure it's not listed with a Selector Control or something other than DateTimeEdit.  If it is, you can delete, change the control, and re-add.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the screen looks fine.